# Facebook API not returning work and position fields in people query

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Querying user data on Facebook Graph via the Javascript API will not return all fields.

For example, the following query:

```
/search?q=David Blades&type=user&fields=location,work,id,name,picture,link
```

Returns everything except work and location.

Does anybody know the reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because these fields are not publicly available, please refer to the [`User`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object:

```
Name       Permission  
id         No access_token required  
name       No access_token required  
...  
location   user_location or friends_location
```